# iOS - Is it possible to only rotate navigation bar buttons when device rotates?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, rotation

I'm just wondering is it possible to stop UINavigationBarItem from rotation with the device, I mean when the app launches at portrait mode, the navigation bar is at the "top" side of the device. Once user rotates the device, the "left" or "right" side will become the new "top" side, and the navigation bar will rotates to the new "top" bar. And is it possible to stop this behaviour, like rotating everything other than the navigation bar? Even better, can I rotate the navigation bar buttons so user can still see the normal button icon?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible options:

The first is to disable rotation for your app. Then write your own custom rotation monitoring for UIDevice orientation. Then when the device orientation changes, adjust your buttons and UI manually.

The second is to allow rotation, but create a custom navigation bar that doesn't rotate. This navigation bar would have to be completely custom, because conforming to UIToolbar means having a delegate that specifies top or bottom. Left or right isn't an option.

Neither one of these is a good option, and I don't think going forward with the idea would give your users a good experience. Having something standard not respond as expected could be jarring.

If you do choose to do this, I would recommend the second option, as it will probably require less work.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation, it helped me a lot!